# Is there no punishment to slaughtering an animal on Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, masechet-yoma, kodshim

Well I know that generally it's אסור (if not for פיקוח נפש). My question is really regarding slaughtering a קרבן in the בית המקדש outside of the עבודת היום.

The gemara in יומא (סב:) has a discussion about slaughtering the שעיר לעזאזל outside of the ביהמ"ק. The discussion is if he's חייב משום שיחוטי חוץ. What happened to Yom kippur?? So what that the animal is קדשים, does that take away the issur of נטילת נשמה on יום כיפור?

Comment: Maybe it's just asking what else it violates? That'd still be a coherent question

Comment: שעיר לעזאזל is required by the torah on yom kippur. It must be done by throwing it over the cliff. Since it is part of the avodah there is no isur if it is done properly.